# (iframe) src ../ path

Tags: javascript, iframe, src

So, this is a snippet in my code which doesn't seem to work. Basically the aim of this snippet is to load a text file in an iframe and store its content into a variable.
I previously used XMLHttpRequest but I found out that XMLHttpRequest does not work on local files, due to security vulnerabilities. So I decided to try use iframe.

```
  iproduct = document.createElement("iframe");
  iproduct.src = "../assets/products/50020002/info.txt";
  iproduct.id = 'productinfo';
  iproduct.onload = function () {
    productvalid = true;
    productinfo = document.getElementById('productinfo').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "").split("\n");
    console.log(productinfo);
    document.head.removeChild(iproduct);
  };
  document.head.appendChild(iproduct);
```

So right now my directory hierarchy is:

```
+---assets
|   \---products
|       +---50010001
|       \---50020002
|           \---info.txt
+---site
    +---blank.html
    +---product.html
    \---info.txt
```

So product.html is where the code should be running, and the blank.html (0KB) is for testing.
However, when I replace the **iproduct.src = "../assets/products/50020002/info.txt"** to **iproduct.src = "info.txt"**, the snippet works as it should.

How come the original source exists? Is it like the same issue as the XMLHttpRequest, the security flaw?

Comment: If ajax is subject to javascripts same origin policy and doesn't allow files from the local filesystem, what makes you think an iFrame is any different ?

Comment: Well, I was thinking because if I moved the info.txt into a subdirectory relative to the html files (site/folder/info.txt), and change the iframe source to "folder/info.txt", it works, unlike XMLHttpRequest which doesn't work at all

Comment: `iframe` is invalid content within `head`.

Comment: Actually, I originall put iframe in the document body, but as this code is somewhat necessary for the document to form, I placed it in the head

Comment: Building on putting it in the body instead, I can see it in the page (obviously), but I am unable to get the actual content `iproduct.innerHTML` is an empty string, `iproduct.contentDocument` is null, `iproduct.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML` gives **Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'**